# How to write our own query in Sync Adapter?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I need to use `Sync Adapter` where we need to use `ContentProvider` as a mandatory part.

- Here I have to write my own queries based on my requirements.
- How to write it
- How to pass value from  `Sync Adapter`to activity or vice versa.

How can I do this. I cannot find any working model on this am really confused with this  `Sync Adapter`concept.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a content provider to fetch data in your app. Its just recommended. You could create a stub content provider to fool the sync adapter and return null in all its query methods. See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-stub-provider.html) for more detail. You can directly access your Shared Preference or sqlite database in your sync adapter and query them.

As for passing the the value from sync adapter to Activity is concerned, that is not at all advisable because the purpose of sync adapter is to sync your data in the background even if your app is not operational in the background. So just imagine that you try to pass the value from the sync adapter to the activity but your app isn't even running then it would result in an Exception as the Activity hasn't even been created.

**Solution -** Maintain a local sqlite database or SharedPreference(if the data is small) for your app and keep syncing the data in your database through the sync adapter. And whenever you need this data in your activity, you could simply fetch this from your local database as it will be regularly updated automatically through the sync adapter.

Comment: my doubt is when network available it will work as it will direcly send data to server if not store that values in local db and send when network available does syncadapter model is right way

Comment: Yes sync adapter will send data automatically from your local database whenever internet is available. But when you gotta handle storing data to local database when internet is not there yourself. Sync adapter will not do anything when internet is not present.